# document.execCommand('heading' ..') in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to use the rich-text editing command functions as described in MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)

The API for this seems fairly simple. Select some text, and execute the command, and it'll wrap the content with it. Cool stuff!

In Firefox (Aurora), this works great:

```
document.execCommand('heading', false, 'H1');
```

However the same command in Chrome returns nothing. Is this not implemented the same way (or at all) in Chrome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I am afraid Chrome does not support the **heading** command yet. You can check this page in Chrome for available commands: http://tifftiff.de/contenteditable/compliance_test.html

What you are looking for is the **formatBlock** command used like so:

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<h1>');
```

Comment: the formatBlock command formats the whole block - as the name would suggest - rather than the selection. Is there any known fix to this?

Comment: If anybody else arrives here, I found I had to use `document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'h1');` if I wanted to be able to query the current value later with `document.queryCommandValue( 'formatBlock' )`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to only modify the selected text.

```
borto = {
            tmpEl: document.createElement('div'),
            /* create element like in jquery with string <tag attribute1 attribute2 /> or <tag attribute1></tag> */
            htmlToDom: function(htmlEl){
                borto.tmpEl.innerHTML = htmlEl;
                return borto.tmpEl.children[0]
            },
            wrapSelection: function(htmlEl){
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                // In firefox we can select multiple area, so they are multiple range
                for(var i = sel.rangeCount;i--;){
                    var wrapper = borto.htmlToDom(htmlEl)
                    var range = sel.getRangeAt(i);
                    wrapper.appendChild(range.extractContents());
                    range.insertNode(wrapper);
                }
            }
        }
```

For exemple to put the selected text in h1 tag:

```
borto.wrapSelection('<h1/>')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/31pncq01/ exemple for title h1, h2

Answer (score 1):

You can create it with three moves, like this...

```
var S=window.getSelection();

document.execCommand('delete',false,'');

document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'<h1>'+S+'</h1>');
```